# Finding a record with apostrophe using LIKE

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to find a below record

```
O'GRAD
```

I wanted to use LIKE

```
LIKE 'O'GRAD'
```

But i come across a problem with apostrophe.
What would be the best way around it?

Comment: Why LIKE without wildcards? Simply do `= 'O''GRAD'`

Answer (score 0):

Double up the apostrophe

```
LIKE 'O''GRAD'
```

or use the Q syntax

```
LIKE q'{O'GRAD}'
```

Answer (score 0):

if your Oracle DB version is `10g` or `upper` you may use :

```
select * 
  from mytable t
 where t.col1 like '%'||q'$O'GRAD$'||'%';
/
```

or classically add an extra quote to existing quote

```
select * 
  from mytable t
 where like '%'||'O''GRAD'||'%';
/
```

to overcome the single quotation mark problem.